# tzupdate for openJDK

Tags: datetime, timezone, java, jdk1.7

we use openJDK 7 and it seems Oracle's tzupdater does not support it.

```
    # java -jar /tmp/tz/tzupdater.jar -u -v
    java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre
    java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
    java.version: 1.7.0_09-icedtea
    JRE time zone data version: tzdata2012c
    Theres no tzdata available for this Java runtime.
```

from where can I download the tzupdater for openJDK?

Comment: Why did you tag jdk1.6?